# Wavesurfer blowing up if loadBlob method receives 0 length blob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

We're using [Wavesurfer.js](http://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/methods.html) to play audio via the HTML5 audio tag on our web page. If a user hits "play" on a record that does not contain a source (i.e. the audio has been deleted but the record on the table remains) we get the below error in the console.

Stepping through the code in the debugger I found it is this method call below that is the start of the problem. Each time we send a `blob` with a lenght of zero through this error appears:

> Error decoding audiobuffer
>
> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data

**jQuery**

```
wavesurfer.loadBlob(audioBlob);
```

Using Chrome's debugger again, I can pinpoint the method throwing this exception (pasted below), however I can't step into the `backend` method to see what is going on.

**Wavesurfer.js**

```
decodeArrayBuffer: function(a, b) {
    this.backend.decodeArrayBuffer(a, this.fireEvent.bind(this, "decoded"), this.fireEvent.bind(this, "error", "Error decoding audiobuffer")),
    this.tmpEvents.push(this.once("decoded", b))
},
```

My question is: has anyone familiar with `Wavesurfer` had a similar issue and/or know how to go about either sending in an empty `blob` so the `decodeArrayBuffer` method doesn't throw an exception?